# How to access Backbone model ID from a fetch request on server side

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js, get

In an attempt to learn how BackboneJS works, I am building a PHP script with basic CRUD cabibilities. My problem is, when BackboneJS sends a "Fetch" request (GET) it will send an ID encoded in JSON. My problem is, how can I handle this on the server?

I have tried:
`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

or just handling it via the `$_GET` array.

I simply need to get the ID that comes through, so I can do some DB work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the ID from `_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot : "/students"
});

var student = new Student({id:123});

student.fetch();
```

url that is hit is `www.yourdomain.com/students/123`

Hence you need to parse it out from the request uri.

In a `model.fetch()` ID is not passed as Request payload, but as part of the url it self.
ID along with all other attributes are passed as request payload for `model.put()`. `model.save()` does not have any id, attributes are passed as request payload in which case
 you need to

`$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`